# Linq-Extensions, code won't return even values c#

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-objects

I got a question about the use of lambda expressions.

There was a short assignment in a Textbook where a sequence of integers  `0,2,4,8,7,10,3,2` was given and starting from the third item, only integer values shall be returned, using `Skip()` and `TakeWhile()`. I thought I got it right, but only `4,8`was returned, so I had a sneak-peek at the solution and mine was virtually the same.

Can you guys help me out?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SkipTake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] sequence= new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 8, 7, 10 , 3, 2 };
            var select = sequence.Skip(2).TakeWhile(n => n % 2 ==0 );
            foreach (var item in select)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TakeWhile` will stop at 7. Use the Where clause

```
var select = sequence.Skip(2).Where(n => n % 2 ==0 );
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! Once the Predicate returns `false`, that's it. I should have read more precisely >.<

Answer (score 0):

Your query stops when processing the item "7" which is how TakeWhile command behaves.